# What is the meaning of this な?

Tags: meaning, particles

> 少なくともあなた自身は 見たら抜かずにはいられないほど嫌い、な様ではないようですし

So , what does this な　in {な様} mean ?

Comment: 嫌いisな形容詞。i think you misplaced comma.

Comment: Source please! Typos and mistransliterations abound.

Comment: BJCUAI@ https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1330081383

Answer (score 4):

Simply, it is な used as part of a na-adjective. Without a comma, do the following sentences make sense to you?

> あなたは寿司が嫌いなようだ。 You seem to hate sushi.
>
> 試験は簡単なようですね。 Looks like the exam is easy.

If yes, the な in question is exactly the same. Of course, normally, no comma is placed before な, but since this 嫌い is modified by a relatively long adverbial clause (見たら抜かずにはいられないほど), I guess he wanted to make a pause there. You should not do this in formal sentences.